# UIWebView doesn't respond to touches when drawn off screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, uiwebview

Ok, so I have a UIScrollView that contains several subviews, the subview I am having difficulties with is the UIWebView. When the webview is displayed on screen without having to scroll down the UIScrollView, everything works great ([figure 1](http://d.pr/y02f)).

Where the problem starts is when the webview is loaded off the screen ([figure 2](http://d.pr/CmhP)), and scrolling is needed to view it ([figure 3](http://d.pr/Yvuv)). The webview no longer responds to any user interaction.

I've tried some basic things like reloading the webview after the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating delegate is called, but nothing seemed to work. Has anyone encountered this before or have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: There may be a workaround but Apple's docs for UIScrollView states: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Comment: I did glance by this, I was hoping this wouldn't be a concern since my UIWebView is autoresized according to its content and scrolling is disabled within the webview. Perhaps I was wrong but still hoping for a workaround :/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was working perfectly all along. Only problem was I had a wrapper UIView that contained the imageView and webview, but the wrapper wasn't getting resized, so touches outside its bounds weren't being respected. I just want to mention, a webview really shouldn't be placed in a scrollview. I'm only doing this because the webview is being sized according to its content and has scrolling disabled. Plus, there are currently no other views in the documentation that support links without heavy modification.